# Manage multi Sites

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to find a solution for the next problem.

For one hand, i have a site and in one page of this site i have webContents with links to others Liferay independent sites.

The requirement is to integrate this linked sites in the main site in order to keep the main site URL, menu and theme..., i want to ask the best solution to implement this task. For now, I've thinked this solutions:
I can use the same Web Content but when click on the link, instead of open the URL in a new window, i can open an Iframe with the site linked. This solution have the problem of the have two menus in the page, two scrolls, and the most important problem. Both sites have login and client wants that if I'm logged in in the Parent site, in the moment to open the other site in the Iframe, they want to open this site when the user logged in, is it possible?
I can try to create parent and childs sites, but i don't really know how its work.

Basically, i'm trying to find a solution more than an implementation. Do you faced of this kind of problem before?

Kind regards,

​​​​​​​Íñigo

Comment: Why not a batch procedure to fix/change the existing urls with new ones?

Comment: I can´t understand your solution, its not about URL's. Now, we have a link in main site to open in a new page the second site. What is wanted is, instead of open a new window with the site, its to keeping in the same site, but showing the other when clicking the link.

Comment: "keeping in the same site, but showing the other when clicking the link"  .. can you draw it pls?